# Using RXJS to drive an 'activity' light

Tags: rxjs

I have a "db doing stuff" Subject that outputs true/false for 'is saving' / 'no longer saving'. This happens as the 'begin' and 'end' phases of saving of the object occur.

I'd like to use that to drive a UI symbol that shows three states:

- Idle
- Saving
- Done

I would like:

- 'Idle' to appear when nothing is going on (the default state)
- 'Saving' to appear immediately the subject outputs 'true'. This should be the case as long as a save operation is in progress.
- 'Done' to appear after the Subject emits 'false' (no longer saving), for a period of 1s. 'Idle' appears after the 1s has elapsed.

My existing Subject outputs true/false when saving/done_saving the object.  That's ideal from its own point of view as it knows nothing about UI/feedback.

What's a good way to to do this in RX?
Is this even a good fit for Rx?

Currently using rxjs-5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your activity light UI is the only thing that needs to interpret the stream this way, you can handle it in the subscription:

```
myDbActivityFunction()
.subscribe((isDbActive: boolean) => {
    if(isDbActive) {
        myUiState = 'Saving';
    }
    else {
        myUiState = 'Done';
        Observable.interval(1000).take(1)            
        .subscribe(x => { myUiState = 'Idle';});
        //you could replace the above two lines with a setTimeout function
    }
});
```

If you want to go the next mile, the more Rx-y way would be to transform your data source (e.g. database status callbacks) into an Observable stream that emits the data how you want it, rather than managing it with logic in the subscription. We'd need more information about your database service to look at that.

Comment: thanks for the post. I've a very simple DB wrapper that just emits "true" when saving starts and "false" then "true" when it's done (ignoring errors for the moment). Is that not already an observable stream?         

e.g: it does         this.save_notifications.next(SavingState.StartedSaving);   It's using an enum as I began pondering the idea of trying to emit the three states directly from the observable. Then I asked here :)

This is all at: https://github.com/scornflake/scheduler (the SchedulerDatabase class), out of interest.

Comment: @NeilClayton I took a look. Your approach works fine, but [this article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93) explains why using `.next()` to imperatively push emissions is not idiomatic RxJS. Ideally you’d wrap your async calls (e.g. `db.get()`) to return Observables that complete, then compose/merge them into an aggregate stream that your UI subscribes to. That way you subscribe to a finite stream and don’t have to worry about unsubscribing. Plus then your emissions aren’t side effects, but return values handed back to the calling component/UI.

Comment: Right. That makes a lot of sense, thanks for pointing that out. I'll have another crack at some point then.